# Trying to spit sentence into array with words

Tags: php, string

I am trying to split a sentence into an array with words, one word as each element, in PHP if there is more than one word in the sentence. If there is only one word in the sentence, then I just print that one word.

My issue is when I split the sentence into words delimited by a space and put the contents into an array. I do this all using explode. But when I run through the array that explode apparently makes, it says there is nothing in the array when I try to print each item.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['check'])){
    $input = trim($_GET['check']);
    $sentence='';
    if(stripos($input, ' ')!==false){
        $sentence = explode(' ', $input);
        foreach($sentence as $item){
             echo $item;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo $input;
    }
}
```

Why is `echo $item;` printing nothing? Why isn't there anything in the array $sentence?

Comment: What is your HTML form? you're using `$_GET`... check out [CodePad](http://codepad.org/mM7uybVp)

Comment: have you done a `var_dump($_GET)`? It seems that `'check'` may be set but maybe the value is not.

Comment: @UnholyRanger It is there a the form has a method of get and the text-input-field has a name of check. The code in my question is just my php. The HTML is outside the PHP.

Comment: @UnholyRanger Thank you. I checked and it was empty / not set. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine. Make sure you're getting the variable. You can do a `print_r($_GET);`

You can also just do this:

```
<?php
$_GET['check'] = 'Hey how are you?';
if (isset($_GET['check'])) {
    // each word is now an element in the array
    $arr = explode(' ', trim($_GET['check']));
}
// piece each word back together with a space
echo implode(' ', $arr);
?>
```

It doesn't matter if it's a single word or multiple words.

**UPDATE**: If you really want to check if the user has entered one word or more than one word you can do this:

```
<?php
$_GET['check'] = 'Hey how are you?';
if (str_word_count($_GET['check']) > 1) {
    echo 'More than one word';
} else {
    echo 'Only one word';
}
?>
```

Check out [**str_word_count**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Comment: if his code works, why point him to a new way? It would help more to find the root cause of the issue than to change what works.

Comment: Well if it works then I guess I can't show him the root cause can I? Just trying to decrease the amount of code he's using. That's all. Less code should mean less room for error right? Hah.

Comment: I have separated it into if it is one word or multiple words because that is going to make later on.

Comment: @UnholyRanger yes, exactly.

Comment: My ultimate goal is not to echo each word, but to do one thing if it is a one word user input and another thing if it is multi-word input.